# knockout bind handlers update is not firing for observableArray changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, knockout-binding-handlers

I am trying to access multiple values through single bind handler, in case of observableArray changes which is inside the valuesAccessor binding object, the bind handler update is not firing.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        console.log("INIT");
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
         var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

         ko.utils.arrayForEach(value,function(binding){            
                var value = ko.unwrap(binding);
        });
        console.log("IT WORKS!");
     }
  };

<select data-bind="
    options: Options,
     chosen: {options: Options}
"></select>
```

Demo: ([also on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzTg4/11/)):

```js
    ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            console.log("INIT");
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
             var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
             
             ko.utils.arrayForEach(value,function(binding){            
              var value = ko.unwrap(binding);
            });
            console.log("IT WORKS!");
        }
    };

    function Model() {

        this.Options = ko.observableArray(opt1);
        this.Reload = function () {
            if (!this.index) {
                this.Options(opt2);
                this.index = 1;
            } else {
                this.Options(opt1);
                this.index = 0;
            }
            this.Options.valueHasMutated();
        };
        this.index = 0;

    }

    var opt1 = [{
        Text: "1",
        Value: "1"
    }, {
        Text: "2",
        Value: "2"
    }, ];
    var opt2 = [{
        Text: "3",
        Value: "3"
    }, {
        Text: "4",
        Value: "4"
    }, ];
    ko.applyBindings(new Model());
```

```html
<select data-bind="
        options: Options,
        value: Selection,
        optionsText: 'Text',
        optionsValue: 'Value',
        chosen: {options: Options}
    "></select>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: Reload" value="reload" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tell us what it's *meant* to do, and what you see it doing instead. Don't make us guess.

Comment: Separately: If you can make a fiddle, 9/10ths of the time you can do a Stack Snippet right here on site (the `<>` button), which is preferred. (Both is fine too.) I've done it for you this time. Your question was leaving out important code before (questions cannot rely on off-site content).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `chosen` binding isn't actually accessing the observable array, so when it mutates, knockout doesn't recall your `update` handler because it doesn't think anything has changed that it's using.

With this binding:

```
chosen: {options: Options}
```

You're binding an entirely new object (with an `options` property pointing at your `Options` observable array).  This means that when you do

```
var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
```

`value` now contains: `{options: <observableArrayFunction>}` - you need to actually access the `options` property on it in order for knockout to register the link:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(value.options(),function(binding){            

});
```

If you make this change, you'll see that `"IT WORKS!"` is now logged when it updates.  It actually gets logged twice, once because you're updating the array, and another because you're calling `valueHasMutated`.

Updated snippet (with the extra `valueHasMutated` removed):

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            console.log("INIT");
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
             var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
             
             ko.utils.arrayForEach(value.options(),function(binding){            
              var value = ko.unwrap(binding);
            });
            console.log("IT WORKS!");
        }
    };

    function Model() {

        this.Options = ko.observableArray(opt1);
        this.Reload = function () {
            if (!this.index) {
                this.Options(opt2);
                this.index = 1;
            } else {
                this.Options(opt1);
                this.index = 0;
            }
        };
        this.index = 0;

    }

    var opt1 = [{
        Text: "1",
        Value: "1"
    }, {
        Text: "2",
        Value: "2"
    }, ];
    var opt2 = [{
        Text: "3",
        Value: "3"
    }, {
        Text: "4",
        Value: "4"
    }, ];
    ko.applyBindings(new Model());
```

```html
<select data-bind="
        options: Options,
        value: Selection,
        optionsText: 'Text',
        optionsValue: 'Value',
        chosen: {options: Options}
    "></select>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: Reload" value="reload" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```